# Calculate difference between values in rows by group

Tags: python, pandas

I have `df` like this:

[image]

I need to calculate difference between `X1, X2, X3, X4 and X5` for each company, but I know only how to calculate difference between whole column.

```
df['dX1'] = df['X1'].shift(-1) - df['X1']
df['dX2'] = df['X2'].shift(-1) - df['X2']
df['dX3'] = df['X3'].shift(-1) - df['X3']
...
```

It's bad approach because it's substracting `X1` on line `74` with `X1` on line `73` (and that's 2 different companies, that makes no sense).

My question is, how to calculate difference between row values but for every period and for every company. E.g.

[image]

(I can load csvs one by one and calculate diff for each company, then merge all into one list, but it will take 2 days because i have 700 csv files).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
cols = ['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5']
df1 = df.groupby('company')[cols].diff(-1)
```

Comment: will check, just wanted `diff(-1)` because last row should be None, tnx