# Pandas diff between rows by value in row and value in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops, key

I got dataframe with a history of making contracts with employees.
Employees may appear in the records several times.
Target documents represents in 3 types.
The goal is to calculate time that particular employee was working in company.
I found a solution. but the execution time of the code is almost 2 hours.
Is there any more fast and convinient way to do this?

Original table is about 200000+ rows

Here is sample of its structure:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'name': ['John Johnson', 'John Johnson', 'John Johnson', 'John Johnson', 'Tom Thompson', 'Tom Thompson',
                            'Steve Stevens', 'Steve Stevens', 'Steve Stevens', 'Steve Stevens', 'Steve Stevens', 
                            'Tom Thompson', 'Tom Thompson', 'Tom Thompson', 'Tom Thompson'], 
                   'doc_type': ['opening_document','any_other_document','any_other_document','closing_document2','opening_document','any_other_document',
                                'opening_document','any_other_document','closing_document1','opening_document','closing_document2',
                               'any_other_document','closing_document1','any_other_document','opening_document'], 
                   'date': pd.to_datetime(['2017-1-1', '2017-1-2', '2017-1-10', '2017-1-15', '2017-1-16', '2017-1-17',
                                '2018-1-2', '2018-1-10', '2018-1-15', '2018-1-16', '2018-1-30',
                                '2017-2-1', '2017-2-4', '2017-3-10', '2017-5-15'])
                  })

# sort by date
df = df.sort_values(by='date').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
+----+---------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|    |     name      |      doc_type      |        date         |
|----+---------------+--------------------+---------------------|
|  0 | John Johnson  |  opening_document  | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  1 | John Johnson  | any_other_document | 2017-01-02 00:00:00 |
|  2 | John Johnson  | any_other_document | 2017-01-10 00:00:00 |
|  3 | John Johnson  | closing_document2  | 2017-01-15 00:00:00 |
|  4 | Tom Thompson  |  opening_document  | 2017-01-16 00:00:00 |
|  5 | Tom Thompson  | any_other_document | 2017-01-17 00:00:00 |
|  6 | Tom Thompson  | any_other_document | 2017-02-01 00:00:00 |
|  7 | Tom Thompson  | closing_document1  | 2017-02-04 00:00:00 |
|  8 | Tom Thompson  | any_other_document | 2017-03-10 00:00:00 |
|  9 | Tom Thompson  |  opening_document  | 2017-05-15 00:00:00 |
| 10 | Steve Stevens |  opening_document  | 2018-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 11 | Steve Stevens | any_other_document | 2018-01-10 00:00:00 |
| 12 | Steve Stevens | closing_document1  | 2018-01-15 00:00:00 |
| 13 | Steve Stevens |  opening_document  | 2018-01-16 00:00:00 |
| 14 | Steve Stevens | closing_document2  | 2018-01-30 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

I need to calculate difference in time between *opening_document* and (*closing_document1* or *closing_document2*)
All of the documents (not only target one) represents like rows

## my script with correct output:

```
%%time

# since name is not enough for correct JOIN we need to make a new unique key
# logic is based on information according to which before closing doc_type there always opening type (because you cant lay off who you not hired yet)

df['key'] = np.nan                   # create new empty column

count_key = 0                        # key counter
df['key'][count_key] = count_key     # assign key 0 for row 0 

for i in range(1, len(df)):          # start with row 1
    store = df['doc_type'][i] 
    if store != 'opening_document':
        df['key'][i] = count_key     # if row is NOT 'opening_document' then keep key the same
    else:
        count_key += 1               # else change key
        df['key'][i] = count_key     # and assing it for current row
        
  # just statusbar for make sure that something happening
    sys.stdout.write('\r')             
    sys.stdout.write("[%-20s] %d%%" % ('='*round(20*(i/(len(df)-1))), (100/(len(df)-1))*i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    
print('\n')
```

In original dataframe **Wall time: 1h 29min 53s**

It gives us an additional key by which you can unambiguously determine how to JOIN

```
+----+---------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------+
|    |     name      |      doc_type      |        date         |   key |
|----+---------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------|
|  0 | John Johnson  |  opening_document  | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |     0 |
|  1 | John Johnson  | any_other_document | 2017-01-02 00:00:00 |     0 |
|  2 | John Johnson  | any_other_document | 2017-01-10 00:00:00 |     0 |
|  3 | John Johnson  | closing_document2  | 2017-01-15 00:00:00 |     0 |
|  4 | Tom Thompson  |  opening_document  | 2017-01-16 00:00:00 |     1 |
|  5 | Tom Thompson  | any_other_document | 2017-01-17 00:00:00 |     1 |
|  6 | Tom Thompson  | any_other_document | 2017-02-01 00:00:00 |     1 |
|  7 | Tom Thompson  | closing_document1  | 2017-02-04 00:00:00 |     1 |
|  8 | Tom Thompson  | any_other_document | 2017-03-10 00:00:00 |     1 |
|  9 | Tom Thompson  |  opening_document  | 2017-05-15 00:00:00 |     2 |
| 10 | Steve Stevens |  opening_document  | 2018-01-02 00:00:00 |     3 |
| 11 | Steve Stevens | any_other_document | 2018-01-10 00:00:00 |     3 |
| 12 | Steve Stevens | closing_document1  | 2018-01-15 00:00:00 |     3 |
| 13 | Steve Stevens |  opening_document  | 2018-01-16 00:00:00 |     4 |
| 14 | Steve Stevens | closing_document2  | 2018-01-30 00:00:00 |     4 |
+----+---------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

Merge for "convert" rows into cols by name and new key then calculate difference between open and close in days

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df.loc[df['doc_type']=='opening_document'],
                     df.loc[df['doc_type'].isin(['closing_document1','closing_document2'])], 
                     on=['name','key'], 
                     how='left')

df_merged['time_diff'] = df_merged['date_y'] - df_merged['date_x']
```

Final correct output:

```
    name           doc_type_x        date_x                 key  doc_type_y         date_y               time_diff
--  -------------  ----------------  -------------------  -----  -----------------  -------------------  ----------------
 0  John Johnson   opening_document  2017-01-01 00:00:00      0  closing_document2  2017-01-15 00:00:00  14 days 00:00:00
 1  Tom Thompson   opening_document  2017-01-16 00:00:00      1  closing_document1  2017-02-04 00:00:00  19 days 00:00:00
 2  Tom Thompson   opening_document  2017-05-15 00:00:00      2  nan                NaT                  NaT
 3  Steve Stevens  opening_document  2018-01-02 00:00:00      3  closing_document1  2018-01-15 00:00:00  13 days 00:00:00
 4  Steve Stevens  opening_document  2018-01-16 00:00:00      4  closing_document2  2018-01-30 00:00:00  14 days 00:00:00
```

The best solution I found without using a loop is diff() method
But it turns out that we cant know which "block" we subtract

Instead of loop do this:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['doc_type'].isin(['opening_document','closing_document1','closing_document2'])].sort_values(by='date').reset_index(drop=True)
df1['diff'] = df1['date'].diff(-1)*(-1)
df1 = df1[df1['doc_type']=='opening_document'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
+----+---------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|    |     name      |     doc_type     |        date         |       diff        |
|----+---------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------|
|  0 | John Johnson  | opening_document | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 14 days 00:00:00  |
|  1 | Tom Thompson  | opening_document | 2017-01-16 00:00:00 | 19 days 00:00:00  |
|  2 | Tom Thompson  | opening_document | 2017-05-15 00:00:00 | 232 days 00:00:00 |
|  3 | Steve Stevens | opening_document | 2018-01-02 00:00:00 | 13 days 00:00:00  |
|  4 | Steve Stevens | opening_document | 2018-01-16 00:00:00 | 14 days 00:00:00  |
+----+---------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

Value in row with index 2 is wrong. there was no any closing document.

## How improve performance and save correct output?

Comment: maybe this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295963/calculate-difference-between-values-in-rows-by-group

Comment: I use diff() in the end. The main problem is no keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve the performance of what you do in the loop `for`, you can do it using `shift` on the column `'name'` to find where it changes, or where `'opening_document'` is in 'doc_type', plus use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to increment the value such as:

```
df['key'] = ((df.name != df.name.shift())|(df.doc_type == 'opening_document')).cumsum()
```

Then using `merge` as you do is probably efficient enough. if you want the key to start at 0, just add `-1` at the end of the code above

EDIT: as each time the name changes, the value in 'doc_type' is `opening_document`, it is possible to only keep the second condition such as:

```
df['key'] = (df.doc_type == 'opening_document').cumsum()
```

Comment: @cbccbd good :) just one remark, if you are sure that each time the name change, the first row is `opening_document` in 'doc_type', you can even remove this condition on the column name such as `df['key'] = (df.doc_type == 'opening_document').cumsum()` would be enough

Comment: @ben-t great! Yes Im sure. Because of filtration before other procedures. Thanks again (: